# How to find out the amount of elements in array created for a struct?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I created a certain struct and then I went on to create an array for the struct in the following manner:

```
struct members
{

char name[32];
intmax_t personalID;

}typedef struct members Member;

Member array_member[100];
```

Later on, I want to know how many elements there are in the array, according to some answers I have read, this should be enough

```
int nrofmembers = sizeof(array_member) / sizeof(array_member[0]);
```

But due to my experience, I know that this is not possible if the array itself is a parameter. So I tried this:

```
int nrofmembers =  sizeof(*array_member) / sizeof(array_member[0]);
```

Unfortunately, this has turned out to be wrong. The value of nrofmembers after this is 1, but that's not true.

Any advice on how to do this?

Comment: If you mean that the array is passed in as an argument to a function, you are correct that it will not work.  The array will decay to a pointer.  You will have to have another argument in the function that you can explicitly pass the size of the array to.

Comment: `sizeof(*array_member)` is the same things as `sizeof(array_member[0]) `, so 1 is the only possible result for `sizeof(*array_member) / sizeof(array_member[0])`

Comment: Oh, that didn't even come to my mind XD, I was dealing with all the errors xDD. So is it possible that i write some like --> nrofpatients = calculatenrofpatients(); and then write a function "void calculatenrofpatients" which deals with the calculation?@ChristianGibbons

Comment: Aha I see, ty for info @UnholySheep

Comment: Passing the size of an array is pretty common. If you don't like this approach you could mark the last element with a special value. This is comparable with strings which should always end with a termination character (`'\0'`). With the end marked you can count the elements until you reach the marked element.

Comment: The basic problem is that you can't use an array type as a parameter type -- if you try to declare a function argument as an array, the compiler silently turns it into a pointer behind your back and you just have a pointer.  So all information about the size of the array is lost.

Comment: couldn't you do a for loop, or a while loop if unknown to print out the values of the array at each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the pointer you cant use this simple compile time method. You need to pass the size of the array to the function

In C you always pass the pointer even if your declaration is `... foo(Member arr[])` or `... foo(Member arr[100])`

```
struct members
{

char name[32];
intmax_t personalID;

}typedef struct members Member;

Member array_member[100];


int foo(Member *arr, size_t size)
{
    /* .... */
}

int main()
{
    /* correct */
    foo(array_member, sizeof(array_member) / sizeof(array_member[0]));
    printf("Hello World");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To add to this, when just passing the array to a function, you are essentially passing the pointer to the first element, which is why you should pass the 'size' of the array as well (like P_J says).